# Generating Joint Density Function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to have Excel calculate a joint density function based on two sets of descriptive statistics generated by the Data Analysis tool?  To explain further, suppose I have two means a and b and two standard deviations c and d.  I would like to form the normal distributions defined by the sets of parameters {a,c} and {b,d} and use them to form a joint density function, which is just the distribution defined by both of these distributions over two axes.

Comment: Could someone explain why this question is poorly posed?  Is it off-topic in some way?

Comment: Mr.114, what is it that you want? Please explain in lay man language

Comment: A few questions: Are you assuming the two random variables are independent? Do you want Excel to return a function for the density surface? Or do you want Excel to do something like generate points in the joint distribution?

Comment: @Excellll Since I think avoiding that assumption would complicate things a lot I've decided to assume they're independent.  The function for the density surface is more what I'm looking for and if I recall correctly I could use the solver from there to get particular points.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two variables that are normally distributed and assumed to be independent, then the joint density function for those two variables is just

```
J(x,y) = P(x)*P(y)
```

where `P(x)` is the probability density function of *X* at *x*, and `P(y)` is the probability density function of *Y* at *y*.

So, in Excel, if you want to find `J(x,y)`, the value of the joint density function for *x* and *y*, you can use the built-in `NORMDIST` function to get what you need.

```
=NORMDIST(x,mean of X,stdev of X,FALSE)*NORMDIST(y,mean of Y,stdev of Y,FALSE)
```

**An example:**
The parameters of two normal random variables *X* and *Y* are given. The heat map below shows the value of the joint density function at integer values of *X* and *Y* from 0 to 10. The formula used to fill the heat map is

```
=NORMDIST(B$5,$B$2,$B$3,FALSE)*NORMDIST($A6,$C$2,$C$3,FALSE)
```

[image]